# How to create SQLite file using database.create() and store in device external storage in IONIC Cordova

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, android-external-storage

1. How to create SQLite file using database.create() and store in device external storage in IONIC Cordova

2)Fetch this data from an another Ionic app running in the same device

I'm Using Ionic 5 (cordova),

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Currently your question is likely to be closed, we need more informations about what you have tried, what went wrong etc, and you should focus on one question at a time. Usually questions asking us to write you the code are not well received in this site, as it is not its purpose